# Angular, ngFor, index

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I get the index i always counting the **viewable** output (1st line, 2ndline, ...) and not the data (data-line 1, data-line 4, ...)?
So I would like to make it related to the ngIf instead of the order of data.

```
data: number []=[0,1,2,10,2,37,4,9,11];


<ul *ngFor="let d of data; let i = index;">
  <ng-container *ngIf="d%2==0">
    <li>Index={{i}} Data={{d}}</li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u7u4ru

I would like to have output

```
Index=0 Data=0
Index=1 Data=2
Index=2 Data=10
Index=3 Data=2
Index=4 Data=4
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter your data in component

```
this.data.filter(x => {
      if (x % 2 == 0)
        return x;
    });
```

Working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-feae8f

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter and a getter with a hook on the last lifecycle event : [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jypxqz?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  data: number []=[0,1,2,10,2,37,4,9,11];
  count = 0;

  get counter() {
    return this.count++;
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.count = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in the component itself not in the template.

Use the [.map()](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#operators) operator to mod your data:

```
this.data = [0,1,2,10,2,37,4,9,11].map(x => { 
    if(x%2 == 0)
        return x;
})
// Remove all empty values.
.filter(n=>!isNaN(n));
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvpyjz)